# How to sanitize custom Customer attributes?

Tags: adminhtml, grid, security, customer-attribute, register

I've created a customer attribute for the Customer model, and I added it to the Customer grid.

This works like magic, simply adding the attribute to the frontend registration and edit forms allows a user to save them, and the admin grid displays them. No problemo.

When viewing the customer grid, however, user inputted html (including  tags!!) is interpreted by the browser. This is a problem.

How can I either:

a) Somehow hijack the post data and clean it up before it's saved to the customer record.

or

b) Clean up data for custom columns as the admin grid is populated.

'a' appears to be the way the latest patch (7405) has fixed many of the core files that handle user input, but I'm more interested in 'b' right now, because this problem is probably exploitable in most 3rd party modules that take user input and display it in an admin grid. I'd like to figure out a way to protect the admin panel from any custom fields.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: escapeHtml() is the usual method for b) and is what wasn't used on the backend views of the customer input email address. Magento still accepts email addresses constructed with `<script>` tags if you bypass the clientside email address validation by shutting off javascript or doing a curl put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out how to accomplish 'b', at least for my own module.

The key was in the column declaration for my attribute within my grid override:

```
    $this->addColumnAfter('Company', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
        'type'   => 'text',
        'index'  => 'company',
        'width'  => '150px'
    ), 'email');
```

The grid widget has several column renderers in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Column/Renderer/, including Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Text, which actually uses the 'escapeHtml' on almost every return:

```
    public function _getValue(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $format = ( $this->getColumn()->getFormat() ) ? $this->getColumn()->getFormat() : null;
    $defaultValue = $this->getColumn()->getDefault();
    if (is_null($format)) {
        // If no format and it column not filtered specified return data as is.
        $data = parent::_getValue($row);
        $string = is_null($data) ? $defaultValue : $data;
        return $this->escapeHtml($string);
    }
    elseif (preg_match_all($this->_variablePattern, $format, $matches)) {
        // Parsing of format string
        $formattedString = $format;
        foreach ($matches[0] as $matchIndex=>$match) {
            $value = $row->getData($matches[1][$matchIndex]);
            $formattedString = str_replace($match, $value, $formattedString);
        }
        return $formattedString;
    } else {
        return $this->escapeHtml($format);
    }
}
```

So why isn't my 'company' column being sanitized!?!?

Turns out, 'text' isn't rendered by Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Text at all, according to this case statement in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column's function _getRendererByType function:

```
    protected function _getRendererByType()
{
    $type = strtolower($this->getType());
    $renderers = $this->getGrid()->getColumnRenderers();

    if (is_array($renderers) && isset($renderers[$type])) {
        return $renderers[$type];
    }

    switch ($type) {
        case 'date':
            $rendererClass = 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_date';
            break;
        case 'datetime':

        ....
        ...   etc... 

        // This is the case I hit here:
        case 'text':
            $rendererClass = 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_longtext';
            break;

        ...
        etc...


        default:
            // This is the rendering class I actually wanted:
            $rendererClass = 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_renderer_text';
            break;
    }
    return $rendererClass;
}
```

So in reality, the renderer for columns identified as 'text', the *longtext* renderer is used (WTF?).

So for me the solution was to either drop the 'text' declaration from my column so it hits the 'default' case (and is then rendered by the 'text' renderer):

```
    $this->addColumnAfter('Company', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
        'index'  => 'company',
        'width'  => '150px'
    ), 'email');
```

... or else add a boolean called "escape", which instructs the longtext renderer to escape html:

```
    $this->addColumnAfter('Company', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
        'type'   => 'text',
        'escape' => true,
        'index'  => 'company',
        'width'  => '150px'
    ), 'email');
```

As far as protecting my customers from other 3rd party modules that display user inputted text in an admin grid, I think I'll probably just override the longtext renderer class an make it always escape on render.